# What are the "Permitted parents" of the audio tag?

Tags: html

According MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), the "Permitted parents" of the audio tags are "*any element that accepts embedded content*", ie: `audio`, `canvas`, [`embed`], `iframe`, `img`, `math`, `object`, `picture`, `svg`, `video` (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#embedded-content).

So, I can not understand how does an `audio` tag, or `canvas`|`iframe`|`img` etc. tags, to be a "Permitted parents" of the `audio` tag, but I'd understand that they can be the `body` tag and some (not all) elements "categorized as flow content" for example `div`, `article`, etc. tags.

Is there an error in the MDN page, or (more likely) I just do not understand?

```html
<audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2083&type=mp3" controls>
  <audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2083&type=mp3" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>

<canvas  width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid black;">
 <audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2083&type=mp3" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>
 Your browser does not support the canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing "embedded content" with "accepts embedded content". The `<audio>` is an embedded content element and its parent is any element that *accepts* embedded content.

Comment: @J08691, thanks. I get it. So in addition to List "Kinds of content" (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#kinds-of-content), it would also contribute to the Elements List (of that list) that accept various types of content (embedded, stream, and c.) this further list exists, or whenever you need to check whether a certain tag accepts a certain type of content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the `audio` element is allowed basically anywhere in a document except in places where it pretty much clearly intuitively would not make sense for it to be used.

So, `audio` is not allowed in the `head`, or in places like: Not as a direct child of a `dl` element (which needs `dt` and `dd`) or not as a direct child of a `ul` element (which needs `li`), etc.

As far as the formal requirements that define where `audio` is normatively allowed, read on…

#### Longer explanation: Actual spec requirements for where `<audio>` is allowed

I think the MDN wording is confusing because [the corresponding requirement in the the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-audio-element) is confusing too. That requirement words it as `audio` being allowed “*Where embedded content is expected*“, but doesn’t directly answer the question “Where is embedded content allowed?…”

Figuring it out is a little convoluted: You have to start by looking at what [“categories”](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#content-categories) the spec [defines the `audio` element to belongs to](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-audio-element), which are:

- **Flow content**.
- **Phrasing content**.
- **Embedded content**.
- If the element has a controls attribute: **Interactive content**.
- If the element has a controls attribute: **Palpable content**.

Among those, the spec also nowhere directly answers the questions “Where is interactive content allowed?” and “Where is palpable content allowed?”

But the spec *does* somewhat more directly answer the questions “Where is flow content allowed?“ and “Where is phrasing content allowed?”—because there are elements whose content models are explicitly defined at being allowed to contain phrasing content and/or flow content.

For example if you look at the [**Content model** section for the `body` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-body-element:concept-element-content-model), you’ll see it says ***Content model***: Flow content. So the `body` element is an allowed parent of the `audio` element (because the `audio` element belongs to the “flow content” category).

And if you look at the [**Content model** section for the `p` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-p-element:concept-element-content-model), you’ll see it says ***Content model***: Phrasing content. So the `p` element is an allowed parent of the `audio` element (because the `audio` element belongs to the “phrasing content” category).

And so on.

If you wanted to put together a complete list of every element that’s an allowed parent of the `audio` element, you could:

1. Go to [the point in the spec where the term **content model** is defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-content-model).
2. Click on the actual boldface term **Content model** there.

If you do that what you’ll see pop up is this:

[image: HTML spec dfn popup for the term “content model”]

All of the bulleted items there are hyperlinks; if you follow them, it will take you directly to the **Content model** section for the corresponding element.

#### How this requirement is implemented in the HTML Checker

If you’re curious about how the [W3C HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) implements this: It doesn’t use an exhaustive list of every element that’s an allowed parent of the `audio` element. Instead it uses a RelaxNG schema which defines things in pretty much the same way the spec does: it has `common.elem.flow` and `common.elem.phrasing` sets of elements that are referenced by the RelaxNG element definitions in the schema.

For example, the RelaxNG schema definition for the `p` element looks like this:

```
p.elem =
    element p { p.inner & p.attrs }
p.attrs =
    (   common.attrs
    &   common.attrs.aria?
    )
p.inner =
    ( text & common.elem.phrasing* )

common.elem.flow |= p.elem
```

So as far as the `p` content model, that’s very simple:

The `p.inner = ( text & common.elem.phrasing* )` says the `p` element can contain any number of `common.elem.phrasing` elements mixed with text.

And then the RelaxNG schema definition for the `audio` element looks like this:

```
audio.elem.flow =
    element audio { audio.inner.flow & audio.attrs }
audio.elem.phrasing =
    element audio { audio.inner.phrasing & audio.attrs }
audio.attrs =
    (   common.attrs
    &   media.attrs
    &   common.attrs.aria.landmark.application?
    )
audio.inner.flow =
    (   media.source
    ,   track.elem*
    ,   common.inner.transparent.flow
    )
audio.inner.phrasing =
    (   media.source
    ,   track.elem*
    ,   common.inner.phrasing
    )

common.elem.flow |= audio.elem.flow
common.elem.phrasing |= audio.elem.phrasing
```

Here we don’t care about the content model but instead what it’s saying about where the `audio` element is allowed. And the last line is the part which causes the `audio` element to be placed in the `common.elem.phrasing` set, which as we saw above is referenced by the `p` element.

So the RelaxNG schema actually closely models how the HTML spec structures the content-model relationships. I guess it’s not any more intuitive to *read* through then the corresponding spec language—but the end result from the point of view of an author using the HTML checker is that if you try to use the `audio` element some place in a document where the RelaxNG schema doesn’t allow it (somewhere where `common.elem.flow` or `common.elem.phrasing` are not allowed), then the checker knows and will give you a clear error message.

Comment: Many thanks. That "W3C HTML checker's method" is very intresting. With it would be possible to do that too, for each tag, a list of its "permitted parents", it would be very convenient to systematic purposes and study. Without having to make individual practical tests for each child tag of all the tags one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, it seems to me that the "Permitted content" classification is a little uncertain too. The `b` tag accepts "Phrasing content" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b), and then `video` tag (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#kinds-of-content-phrasing-content): a **bold** video? :-((

Comment: Yeah `<b><video src=foo></video></b>` is allowed. There’s nothing uncertain about it. While I can’t think of any case where it’d be useful to mark anything up that way, it would also not cause any problems, so there’s no good reason for the spec to explicitly disallow it.